# Software uninstalled from brew still on $PATH

Tags: terminal, homebrew, path

I've uninstalled software from brew (as I want to use a different version), using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1

```
brew uninstall bowtie2
```

And downloaded the software from SourceForge instead, then copied the executables onto the $PATH

```
which bowtie2

> /usr/local/bin/bowtie2
```

However when I try to run the command

```
bowtie2
```

I get the error

```
> -bash: /usr/local/Homebrew/bin/bowtie2: No such file or directory
```

So it's still searching for the old path in the Homebrew folder. How do I change this?

Answer (score 2):

Homebrew likes to create symlinks from `/usr/local/bin/` to `/usr/local/Cellar/`.

You can see if this is the case by running: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/bowtie2`.

That should return a line with arrow syntax (`->`) like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/bowtie2 -> ../Cellar/bowtie2/<someversion>/bin/bowtie2
```

If that's the case, then you can just delete the broken symlink with: `rm /usr/local/bin/bowtie2` (you may need to preface that with `sudo` depending on ownership of `/usr/local/bin/`. It's the broken symlink that is causing `which` to still show `bowtie2` as being located in `/usr/local/bin/`.

You can then move the new binary for bowtie (that you downloaded from SourceForge) into `/usr/local/bin/` or any other folder in your PATH.

Comment: Did this solve your your problem @tc13?

Answer (score 0):

try to:

`ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep bowtie2`

as well as

`find /usr/local | grep bowtie2`

this will give you all info

binary is usually placed here (`*` is just to replace version number):

`/usr/local/Cellar/PROGRAMNAME/*/bin/`

which in your case:

`/usr/local/Cellar/bowtie2/*/bin/`

Answer (score 0):

homebrew are unlink your symbolic links for you via "brew unlink bowtie2"

```
$ brew help unlink
brew unlink [--dry-run] formula:
    Remove symlinks for formula from the Homebrew prefix. This can be useful
    for temporarily disabling a formula:
    brew unlink formula && commands && brew link formula

    If --dry-run or -n is passed, Homebrew will list all files which would
    be unlinked, but will not actually unlink or delete any files.

$ brew unlink bowtie2
```